# firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier with reCaptcha v3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am trying to implement reCaptcha v3 into my site and am currently using React.js and Firebase for Authentication. I was using reCaptcha (v2?) before with Firebase's built in auth method `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier` following the same method as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951731/using-recaptcha-with-firebase). Besides my own need for a reCaptcha, Firebase requires it sometimes for their authentication purposes for Registering/Signing In.

I am unsure on how to use this [react-recaptcha-v3](https://github.com/codeep/react-recaptcha-v3) library and implement it with the `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier` method as I did before. Is there a way I can pass the token directly to Firebase for their authentication purposes? Or maybe I am using the `verifyCallback` from `react-recaptcha-v3` callback function wrong in `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier`? Maybe reCaptcha v3 is not available with `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier` yet? Maybe I should just use the reCaptcha v2 invisible version to achieve the desired effect?

**react-recaptcha-v3 example code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ReCaptcha } from 'react-recaptcha-v3'

class ExampleComponent extends Component {

  verifyCallback = (recaptchaToken) => {
    // Here you will get the final recaptchaToken!!!  
    console.log(recaptchaToken, "<= your recaptcha token")
    // do something with the token?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReCaptcha
            sitekey="your_site_key"
            action='action_name'
            verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

**Current RecaptchaVerifier usage:**

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha', {
        'callback': (response) => {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow.
        },
        'expired-callback': () => {
          // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
          window.recaptchaVerifier.clear()
        }
      })
      window.recaptchaVerifier.render()
```

Comment: I'm looking to rig up a similar flow in a Vue app. How did this unfold? Any luck?

Comment: @krry negative, still waiting for this support to be added, still using Recaptcha v2 :/